# GoogleDrive file download issue

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am able to download file from GoogleDrive API.
Using the following code.

```
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?alt=media",
                     identifier];

    GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:url];
    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
            // Do something with data

            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            NSLog(@"%@", img);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            [self showErrorAlert:error];
        }
    }];
```

It was working fine.(Getting image from data)

Now its not able to compose image.

```
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            NSLog(@"%@", img);
```

Its giving Null.

Comment: what do you want to be shown in log??

Comment: I want to use image. Jus logging it for info.